# group and split columns dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that look like this one:

```
structure(list(group = c("A", "B", "C"), mean_meth1 = c(10, 20, 
30), mean_meth2 = c(15, 25, 35), lower_meth1 = c(7, 17, 27), 
lower_meth2 = c(12, 22, 32), upper_meth1 = c(13, 23, 33), 
upper_meth2 = c(18, 28, 38)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

    group mean_meth1 mean_meth2 lower_meth1 lower_meth2 upper_meth1 upper_meth2
1     A         10         15           7          12          13          18
2     B         20         25          17          22          23          28
3     C         30         35          27          32          33          38
```

3 rows for 3 different groups, A,B,C with two experiments carried out on each group. Each methodology has a mean value, an upper limit and a lower limit. I need to plot this structure and it will be easier if I can get the data.frame in the following shape:

```
  group method mean lower upper
1     A  meth1   10     7    13
2     A  meth2   15    12    18
3     B  meth1   20    17    23
4     B  meth2   25    22    28
5     C  meth1   30    27    33
6     C  meth2   35    32    38
```

I tried with `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from `dplyr` but I haven't got much. Could you guys help me?
Thank you

Comment: try `df %>% pivot_longer(-1, names_to = c(".value", "method"), names_sep = "_")`

Comment: Thank you very much, could you explain the logic to me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you might have been trying to get to was this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-group, names_to = "method") %>%
  separate(method, into = c("variable","method"), sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("group","method"), names_from = "variable")
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  group method  mean lower upper
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     meth1     10     7    13
2 A     meth2     15    12    18
3 B     meth1     20    17    23
4 B     meth2     25    22    28
5 C     meth1     30    27    33
6 C     meth2     35    32    38
```

However, there is a built in special "sentinel" in `pivot_longer`, `.value`. From `help(pivot_longer)`:

> values_to: A string specifying the name of the column to create from the data stored in cell values. If names_to is a character containing the special .value sentinel, this value will be ignored, and the name of the value column will be derived from part of the existing column names.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-group, names_to = c(".value", "method"), names_sep = "_")
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  group method  mean lower upper
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     meth1     10     7    13
2 A     meth2     15    12    18
3 B     meth1     20    17    23
4 B     meth2     25    22    28
5 C     meth1     30    27    33
6 C     meth2     35    32    38
```

Thus, the first half of the column name is ignored and the name fo the value column is derived from that part of the column name, as described in help.